# How to set color and text/font size of picker text?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uipickerview, visual-studio-2022

I use a specific picker setup to mimic the action of a drop down list in Xamarin.iOS.  The code is:

```
    public void ConfigureSelectPicker(UITextField pickerTextField, List<string> theData)
    {
        PickerViewModel MyModel = new PickerViewModel();
        MyModel._pickerSource = theData;
        var picker = new UIPickerView
        {
            Model = MyModel,
            ShowSelectionIndicator = true,
            TintColor = UIColor.Blue
        };
        var screenWidth = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width;
        var pickerToolBar = new UIToolbar(new RectangleF(0, 0, (float)screenWidth, 44)) { BarStyle = UIBarStyle.Default, Translucent = true };
        var flexibleSpaceButton = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace);
        var doneButton = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, (sender, e) => pickerTextField.ResignFirstResponder());
        doneButton.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            pickerTextField.Text = MyModel.SelectedItem;
        };
        pickerToolBar.SetItems(new[] { flexibleSpaceButton, doneButton }, false);

        pickerTextField.InputView = picker;
        pickerTextField.InputAccessoryView = pickerToolBar;
    }
```

The `theData` list contains strings that are truncated in the picker.  Is there a way I can change the font size to make them fit and also the text color?

Comment: there are numerous questions that address doing this natively with `attributedTitleForRow` - the relevant method in Xamarin seems to be [GetAttributedTitle](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/uikit.uipickerviewdelegate.getattributedtitle?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12)

Comment: The only references I've found are Xamarin.Forms, I'm using Xamarin.iOS.  I've looked at what they've done and have been unable to make it work.  I'll take a closer look at the `UIPickerViewDelegate`.

Comment: First issue I get with the `UIPickerViewDelegate` is for the line `public override NSAttributedString GetAttributedTitle (UIPickerView pickerView, int row, int component)` I get the error `no suitable method found to override` and I copied the delegate class code directly from the article.  These are the issues I constantly run into with Xamarin.iOS issues.  A lot of Xamarin.Forms code, which doesn't work with Xarmin.iOS.

Comment: please [edit] your question to include the specific code you need help with

Comment: *" A lot of Xamarin.Forms code, which doesn't work with Xarmin.iOS"* - That *is* `Xamarin.iOS` code. `UIPickerView` is an iOS class; won't compile in cross-platform code, regardless of parameters. It will help if you edit the code in question to show exactly how the code in your comment fits in with the question's code, as well as that error message. (Put in question, everything in that comment, thanks.) This avoids possible confusion, and is easier to follow than reading comments. ALSO show the *class declaration line* of your `UIPickerView` or `UIPickerViewDelegate`. `override` is in that?

Answer (score 0):

You could override **GetView** method in your **UIPickerViewModel**.

```
public override UIKit.UIView GetView(UIKit.UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component, UIKit.UIView view)
{
    
    var pickerLabel = view as UILabel;
    if (pickerLabel == null)
    {
        pickerLabel = new UILabel();
        pickerLabel.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(5);
        pickerLabel.TextColor = UIColor.Red;
    }
    // you should again give the value to the pickerLabel Text based on the row or component of your picker
    if (component = 0)        
    {
        pickerLabel.Text = names[row];
    }
    else
    {
        pickerLabel.Text = row.ToString()        
    }

    return pickerLabel;
}
```

For more info, you could refer to [Picker control in Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/picker) and sample code: [PickerControl](https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/tree/main/PickerControl).

Comment: When you can debug, please check my answer. :)

Comment: My apologies for the delay.  I will be coding this answer and debugging in a few days, time constraints forced me to move on.  I will return to this code, hopefully, shortly.  Your answer looks hopeful, but I had looked at changing/executing a separate model before and wasn't able to make it work.  But I WILL try this method.  Thanks again

Comment: Never mind. If you have any question, share it here and we could try to figure it out.